# Need help to get data out of the output

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am currently developing a Discord bot in node.js and need some help with the output of the npm module I am using ([hypixel-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hypixel-api)).

Currenlty getting this as output: https://hastebin.com/tihepusose.json Now I need some help at this point; How can I get the data from one specific set uuid (will always be different) and get the data like last_save, etc. from the member. Note that there are sometimes multiple profiles or just 1.

My problem is currently getting the data from the member, like last_save or stats.

The following code is how I got the uuid from it but can't get further

```
let memberUUID = Object.values(result.profiles).map((val)=>
 console.log((Object.keys(val.members)[0]))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get details of member from profiles, you can do something like this:

```
    let memberDetails = {};
    Object.values(result.profiles).map((profile)=>
         let uuid = Object.keys(profile.members)[0]
        memberDetails[uuid] = profile.members[uuid];
    )
    /* Now memberDetails has member information like: 
         { "uuid1":{
                    "last_save": 1591213850958,
                    "first_join": 1591208618520,
                    "first_join_hub": 82261,
                    "stats": { "pet_milestone_ores_mined": 7 }
                   },
            "uuid2":{
                    "last_save": 1591213834958,
                    "first_join": 1781208618520,
                    "first_join_hub": 2345,
                    "stats": { "pet_milestone_ores_mined": 7 }
                    }
          }
    /*
```

I am assuming there is only one uuid in members object or at least you are interested in the first one.